# Upgrading from Rails 5.2.8.1 to Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, version-control, rubygems, gemfile

I'm trying to upgrade an old project into new versions of ruby and rails.

ruby 2.5.1 -> ruby 3.1.2
rails 5.2.8.1 -> rails 6.0.3

This is the error im getting:

```
$ bundle
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Resolving dependencies.....
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    actionpack (= 5.2.8.1)

  In Gemfile:
    rails (~> 6.0.3) was resolved to 6.0.3, which depends on
      actionpack (= 6.0.3)

    devise_token_auth (= 1.0.0) was resolved to 1.0.0, which depends on
      devise (> 3.5.2, < 4.6) was resolved to 4.5.0, which depends on
        railties (>= 4.1.0, < 6.0) was resolved to 5.2.8.1, which depends on
          actionpack (= 5.2.8.1)

Deleting your Gemfile.lock file and running `bundle install` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only
the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.


$ rails s
Could not find gem 'rails (~> 6.0.3)' in locally installed gems.
The source contains the following gems matching 'rails':
  * rails-5.2.8.1
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

I was hoping to update my old rails project into newer versions of ruby and rails including working dependencies.

Comment: Deleting the Gemfile.lock might work but that will cause all dependencies to be updated (not just Rails). I think OP might want to 1) update their Gemfile to specify the version of Rails they want and then 2) Run `bundle update rails`

Answer (score 0):

The Devise gem didn't support Ruby on Rails 6.0 until version 4.7. That means when you want to update Rails to 6.0 then you need to update Devise at the same time.

I would try running:

```
bundle update rails device devise_token_auth
```

Btw. Rubygems is a great resource to investigate version dependencies. Here, for example, you can see that [Devise 4.6.2](https://rubygems.org/gems/devise/versions/4.6.2) only support railties < 6.0 but [Devise 4.7.0](https://rubygems.org/gems/devise/versions/4.7.0) had that limitation removed.